# Prove that if $\\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $a\mathbb{N}\cap b\mathbb{N}=(ab)\mathbb{N}.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, natural-numbers

> Prove that if $\\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $a\mathbb{N}\cap b\mathbb{N}=(ab)\mathbb{N}.$

We have $1=\gcd(a,b)\implies au+bv=1$ for some $u,v\in \mathbb{Z}.$ Is it the correct way to prove the above result?

I am stuck here.

Comment: This is an equality of sets. Prove that one set is contained in the other, and vice versa.

Comment: The elements that are in $2\mathbb N$ and $3\mathbb N$ are the elements of $6\mathbb N$, not $1\mathbb N.$ It is true if your replace $\gcd$ with $\operatorname{lcm}.$

Comment: The corrected question requres $\gcd(a,b)=1.$

Comment: By, the way, $u,v\mathbb Z$, not $\mathbb N.$

Comment: Thank you for point out my mistake @ThomasAndrews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you show that $(ab)\mathbb N$ is a subset of both $a\mathbb N$ and $b\mathbb N?$ So $(ab)\mathbb N\subseteq a\mathbb N\cap b\mathbb N?$

Then use $au+bv=1$ to show that if $k\in a\mathbb N\cap b\mathbb N$ then $k\in ab\mathbb N.$

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I have understood what to do now.@ThomasAndrews